# Libpcap filter strings using "vlan" are behaving weirdly

Tags: pcap, libpcap, tcpdump, packet-capture, bpf

I am getting some weird errors when using libpcap pcap_compile
Please let me know if these are known issues or I am making some bpf formating/ordering mistakes

### For example:

1) 
if I pass (protocol_filter and vlan_filter), I see no packets: Like ((arp or udp port 234) and vlan 12)
But if I swap exp as (vlan_filter and protocol_filter), then packet filtering works: Like ((vlan 12) and (arp or udp port 234))

2) If I include vlan with "not" protocols, I get packets with protocol filter applied:
eg: (((vlan 20)) and (not (udp port 3800)) and ((not (tcp)) and (not (udp port 53)) and (not (icmp)) and (not (ip6)) and (not (udp port 5353))))

If I dont include vlan with protocols, I get all packets including tcp, icmp, ip6 etc when bpf is:
(not (udp port 3800)) and ((not (tcp)) and (not (udp port 53)) and (not (icmp)) and (not (ip6)) and (not (udp port 5353))))

3)(((not vlan)) and (not (udp port 3800)) and ((not (tcp)) and (not (udp port 53)) and (not (icmp)) and (not (ip6)) and (not (udp port 5353))))
get all packets including ip6, tcp, etc

(((not vlan)) and (not (udp port 3800)) and (((tcp)) or ((udp port 53)) or ((icmp)) or ((ip6)) or ((udp port 5353)))) dont get even single packet

Comment: Hi Guy Harris, can u please ans this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31190507/libpcap-bpf-for-filter-list-of-exclude-protocols-i-e-not-proto1-or-protp2

Answer (score 2):

`vlan` is weird.

To quote the pcap-filter man page:

```
   vlan [vlan_id]
          True if the packet is an IEEE 802.1Q VLAN packet.  If  [vlan_id]
          is specified, only true if the packet has the specified vlan_id.
          Note that the  first  vlan  keyword  encountered  in  expression
          changes  the decoding offsets for the remainder of expression on
          the assumption that the packet  is  a  VLAN  packet.   The  vlan
          [vlan_id]  expression  may  be used more than once, to filter on
          VLAN hierarchies.  Each use of that  expression  increments  the
          filter offsets by 4.

          For example:
               vlan 100 && vlan 200
          filters on VLAN 200 encapsulated within VLAN 100, and
               vlan && vlan 300 && ip
          filters  IPv4  protocols  encapsulated  in VLAN 300 encapsulated
          within any higher order VLAN.
```

The "Note that the first ***vlan*** keyword encountered in *expression* changes  the decoding offsets for the remainder of *expression* on the assumption that the packet is a VLAN packet." is important here.

This means that *the order of `vlan` and other filters matters*.

So:

> if I pass (protocol_filter and vlan_filter), I see no packets

That's because "protocol_filter" is evaluated based on the assumption that the packet is *not* a VLAN packet; anything that passes that filter is not a VLAN packet, so "vlan_filter" fails.

> But if I swap exp as (vlan_filter and protocol_filter), then packet filtering works

That's because "vlan_filter" checks for a VLAN packet *and* changes the way all subsequent tests are done, so that they assume the packet *is* a VLAN packet; "protocol_filter" is evaluated based on the assumption that the packet *is* a VLAN packet.

> If I include vlan with "not" protocols, I get packets with protocol filter applied: eg: (((vlan 20)) and (not (udp port 3800)) and ((not (tcp)) and (not (udp port 53)) and (not (icmp)) and (not (ip6)) and (not (udp port 5353))))

That filter will match only VLAN packets and, if the packet is for VLAN 20, it will then do all the *other* checks under the assumption that the packet is a VLAN packet - for example, if you're capturing packets with Ethernet headers, and you're checking for IPv4 or IPv6, the other checks will look at the Ethernet type at an offset of 16, not 12.

> If I dont include vlan with protocols, I get all packets including tcp, icmp, ip6 etc when bpf is: (not (udp port 3800)) and ((not (tcp)) and (not (udp port 53)) and (not (icmp)) and (not (ip6)) and (not (udp port 5353))))

That's a little confusing, and it could be argued that it's a bug in libpcap.

"udp port 3800" first checks "is this IPv4 or IPv6", which on Ethernet is done by checking whether the Ethernet type/length field has the value 0x0800 for IPv6 or 0x86dd for IPv6.  If that matches for IPv4, it checks the IPv4 protocol field to see whether it's UDP; if it matches for IPv6, it checks the IPv6 next header field to see whether it's UDP.  If it's UDP, it then checks the source and destination port numbers to see if either one is 3800; if so, the packet matches, otherwise it doesn't match.

"not (udp port 3800)" does the same checks, except that if any of the tests don't match, the packet *does* match, and if any of them match, the packet *doesn't* match.

A VLAN packet has 0x8100 in the Ethernet type/length field, so the checks for IPv4 and IPv6 don't match. Therefore, the "not" filters *do* match.

The bug here is that a UDP packet to or from port 3800 *is* an IPv4 or an IPv6 packet; if it's on a VLAN, it just doesn't happen to, on Ethernet, have 0x0800 or 0x86dd at an offset of 12 from the beginning of the packet, it has 0x8100.

> (((not vlan)) and (not (udp port 3800)) and ((not (tcp)) and (not (udp port 53)) and (not (icmp)) and (not (ip6)) and (not (udp port 5353)))) get all packets including ip6, tcp, etc

That's another libpcap bug - just as "vlan", on Ethernet, causes all subsequent tests to look at the Ethernet type field *after* the VLAN header, so does "not vlan".  But that's wrong for "not vlan", as, if it matches, the packet *isn't* a VLAN packet, so there *is* no VLAN header!

> (((not vlan)) and (not (udp port 3800)) and (((tcp)) or ((udp port 53)) or ((icmp)) or ((ip6)) or ((udp port 5353)))) dont get even single packet

Same problem.

The libpcap/WinPcap bugs might not be *easy* to fix, but I'll look at them when I have time.